# Google Spreadsheet pivot to show hours elapsed

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, pivot, unique

i have a Google Spreadsheet table:

```
user          |  message_id             |   event          |   timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john player   |  ekjf939e9313140_34k    |  delivered       | 04/13/2018 12:56:30
john player   |  ekjf939e9313140_34k    |  opened          | 04/15/2018 16:05:00
john player   |  ekjf939e9313140_34k    |  opened          | 04/16/2018 22:15:20
john player   |  ekjf939e9313140_34k    |  opened          | 04/16/2018 23:47:33
cristian dior |  dsfsk0340344030fkjkj   |  delivered       | 04/12/2018 18:45:21
cristian dior |  dsfsk0340344030fkjkj   |  opened          | 04/13/2018 15:40:17
cristian dior |  dsfsk0340344030fkjkj   |  clicked         | 04/13/2018 16:00:07
cristian dior |  dsfsk0340344030fkjkj   |  clicked         | 04/13/2018 16:04:10
cristian dior |  dsfsk0340344030fkjkj   |  clicked         | 04/14/2018 12:30:11
```

For a user, for each unique message_id, how do i create an Google spreadsheet pivot table that can display hours elapsed between when an email was delivered and when it was opened?

#### Edit:

The table data may contain all possible values.

Comment: @pnuts any idea how this can be done with Appscript or is there another innovative way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=QUERY( ArrayFormula( QUERY({A:C,value(D:D)}, "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1, Col2 pivot Col3")),  "select Col1, Col2, Col4 - Col3 label Col4 - Col3 'Time' format Col4 - Col3 'hh:mm:ss'")`

The first query is to pivot columns by the event.
The second is to calculate the difference.

The result:

```
user              message_id                Time
cristian dior     dsfsk0340344030fkjkj      20:54:56
john player       ekjf939e9313140_34k       03:08:30
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

**Edit**

For multiple events, I suggest to modify the formula:

`=QUERY(QUERY(filter({A:C,value(D:D)},REGEXMATCH(C:C,"delivered|opened")),"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1, Col2 pivot Col3"), "select Col1, Col2, Col4 - Col3 label Col1 'user', Col2 'id', Col4 - Col3 'Time' format Col4 - Col3 'hh:mm:ss'")`

it filters only needed events: `REGEXMATCH(C:C,"delivered|opened")`

Comment: @Max Makrov the problem is there are more than 1 *OPEN* and so even if i choose MIN(datetime), the datetime donot appear in same row. So Subtraction gives blanks for elapsed hours. There is no DISTINCT keyword for USER or SG_MESSAGE_ID, because of which the datetimes appear on different rows. How can this be tackled?

Comment: @sifar786, please add this to your question, the mockup data must contain all possible values.

Comment: i had added another column to the group by because of which the timestamps were displaying in different rows. Now it works! Thanks @MaxMakhrov